# How to integrate Facebook Audience Network using ad mediation (without Admob) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, facebook-audience-network

I am new app development.
I integrated admob in my flutter app but unfortunately I was banned from admob.
Now I decided to go with Facebook Audience Network (FAN).
FAN now only allow Meditation and I couldn't find any flutter tutorial on YouTube for FAN integration with other mediation partners.
Anyone please guide me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mediating one network. You need to show ads with one mediation platform.(Admost/MoPub/ironsource..etc)
FAN approved [platforms](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/bidding/partner-mediation)..

Secondly, You need to check which platform is supporting Flutter [repository](https://pub.dev/)..

While choosing platform you need to check which Platform giving Flutter Repository for **Banner, Interstitial, Native Ads**. Because with this repository you are going to show FAN ads in Mediation platforms (Admost/moPub/ironsource..) placements.
and then add this dependency of [FAN](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/android/add-sdk) in your Android Gradle..

Thirdly, After Implementing (Admost/mopub) Code in your App..

Finally.. You need to add your FAN ads ids in (admost/mopub) account for in mediation options..
Don't forget to use similar ads(Banner=Banner) type id for mediation placements..

And you also dont need FAN repository in Flutter..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding applovin which other network (META/Facebook as well). Easy to integrate and their team response on github as well. Try  - https://pub.dev/packages/applovin_max

Also, Facebook has partnership with AppLovin Max. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/bidding/partner-mediation/max